# Transformation matrix for a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have the follow question here.

> Let $B=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ with $u_1=1$, $u_2=x$, $u_3=x^2$ denote a basis for the space of polynomials of the second order polynomials $P^2$. Let $T(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2)=a_0+a_1(x-1)+a_2(x-1)^2$ be a linear transformation form $P^2$ to itself. Construct the representation matrix $[T]_{BB}.$

My approach was the following:

$T(1+0x+0x^2)=1+0(x-1)+0(x-1)^2=1$. So the 1st column of the transformation matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

$T(0+1x+0x^2)=0+1(x-1)+0(x-1)^2=x-1$. So the 2nd column of the transformation matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

$T(0+0x+1x^2)=0+0(x-1)+1(x-1)^2=(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1$. So the 3rd column of the transformation matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -2\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

So we get that $T_{BB}=\begin{pmatrix}  1 & -1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & -2\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}$.

Is this the right approach? Essentially, I am applying a linear map for the coordinates of the input and I get coordinates for the output which I map. If this isn't correct, what am I doing wrong and can someone correct me? Thanks!

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Thank you for your input!